# Error using EFS volume to differnet VPC with ECS fargate tasks

Tags: amazon-ecs, serverless, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I have an EFS mount volume in VPC-1 and ECS clusters in another VPC-2 and I'm getting error as:

> 'failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr:
> Failed to resolve...'

It's working fine with clusters in same VPC. I have working VPC peering between two VPCs and NFS port opened for EFS SG as well. It is in same region but in different VPCs.